# How to force an autolayout table view cell with size determined by autolayout to go to a height of 0?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, autolayout

I've been asked to convert a `UITableViewCell` with a height determined by autolayout to, in some cases, a table view cell with zero height. What's the most efficient way to do this? I have tried disabling all autolayout constraints related to vertical positioning and height in the appropriate cases, but I still end up with a non-zero height table view cell and the following message:

```
2016-06-02 12:36:06.781 [1336:556232] Warning once only: Detected a case where constraints ambiguously suggest a height of zero for a tableview cell's content view. We're considering the collapse unintentional and using standard height instead.
```

and so I'm getting this:

[image: non-zero table view cell height]

I saw this issue discussed in an existing highly useful SO post ([iOS8 - constraints ambiguously suggest a height of zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25822324/ios8-constraints-ambiguously-suggest-a-height-of-zero)), but I already do have have an autolayout constraint to container bottom from a 'spacer view', which is the resolution suggested there. In particular I use a spacer view of 0 height with layout constraints to have 0 distance from the view to top, bottom, and both leading and trailing.

[image]

[image]

Above you can see the two relevant vertical-related views. I've also checked that everything is wired up to my outlets for when I active/disactivate constraints.

What else should I be troubleshooting here?

Comment: did you override the estimatedHeight delegate method ?

Comment: @AkhileshSharma yes, but that returns a non-zero number for all cases, and I was hoping I wouldn't have to add logic there.

Comment: it never a good option to add a logic inside estimated height method though, the best to have this kind of stuff is alter your datasource and use begin and end update methods to make alteration on the view

Comment: @AkhileshSharma Originally instead of height zero I was changing the row count, but I was asked to take this approach instead.

Comment: You should not be disabling the constraints then, instead have an outlet for height of the container and set it as per your needs when required.

Comment: @AkhileshSharma I tried that but it had layout constraint conflicts and broke them in favor of not having a 0 height

Comment: you need to change the priority of the constraint then. Look into the compression and hugging

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113664/discussion-between-hellob-and-akhilesh-sharma).

Comment: Could be share you cell design? For now what i can suggest you is for constraint like TopSpace, VerticalSpace and BottomSpace set constant value as less than or equal (<=) the if you are setting fixed height to any element then set its constant value to less than equal, and return the cell height 0 for the indexPath you want to make it of height 0.