# Automatic TableView Cell height not working properly

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitableviewautomaticdimension

[image]

I have a tableView Cell like this in storyboard as shown in above image.

I defined  required things in controller necessary for dynamic cell height like this :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 250
}
```

and in viewDidLoad()

```
self.tblView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
self.tblView.estimatedRowHeight = 250
```

But i am getting output like this :

[image]

It seems there are some autolayout conflicts here thats why its occurring or might be i am missing something.
Actually there are lots of elements in this cell & posting constraints screenshots of all will be bit lengthy. If anyone could tell how to approach for resolving this or if u need constraint images I will add in question.

**PS:**
If anyone is coming here I would recommend read below mentioned answers , it will help you:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/26359823/6600624
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/29565073/6600624

Comment: I can confirm this is due to AutoLayout, have you got any warnings in the console at launch ?

Comment: Look like a really complex cell, it should be best if you can upload your storyboard file and confirm all the label that can have dynamic height

Comment: Automatic dimension dependent on Autolayout constraint if it is wrong your cell will always be wrong height

Comment: @AnthoPak yes i got this warning :   Warning once only: Detected a case where constraints ambiguously suggest a height of zero for a tableview cell's content view. We're considering the collapse unintentional and using standard height instead.

Comment: Are you sure that you did setup the constraints properly? Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30299319/why-uitableviewautomaticdimension-not-working

Comment: So that's it, you should review all your constraints to make sure the expected height of the cell is good. Consider removing your constraints and trying again

Comment: I don't find anything similar between the 2 images. Are they supposed to look the same?

Comment: Make sure the compiler will be able to tell the height of the cell with your constraints. Like if you have a label in a contentView label.top -> contentView.top, label.height = 10, label.bottom -> contentView.bottom => cellHeight = 10.

Comment: Can you please show the constraints you have given to that cell?

Comment: Thanks all for your valuable comments, A View is causing conflict . Problem got resolved.